# Excel - compare dates in multiple files and retrieve the latest date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working in an Excel file that has gotten corrupted values - so I need to look at older backup files, and there are a lot of files.

In the main file I have column A that can be matched in any of the files, then I need to look at column B:C and retrieve the date that is closest to today - if it holds a date.

Sorry if this is unclear. Just ask if you have any question!

EDIT: The top left window is that I want to retrieve from the three other files.
I have multiple columns and need the dates to be checked separately, then get the date that is closest to today.
[image: Disired output]

Comment: Please, post a data example and expected output

Comment: Hopefully more understandable now!